# Subsetting matrices of different dimensions

Tags: r, matrix, similarity

Let's say I have two similarity matrices of different dimensions and with some of their `row.names` in common but not in the same order, such as:

```
> m1
            red   yellow     blue    green    black
red    0.000000 2.236068 4.472136 6.708204 8.944272
yellow 2.236068 0.000000 2.236068 4.472136 6.708204
blue   4.472136 2.236068 0.000000 2.236068 4.472136
green  6.708204 4.472136 2.236068 0.000000 2.236068
black  8.944272 6.708204 4.472136 2.236068 0.000000

> m2
         purple    green     blue     red
purple 0.000000 0.081172 4.472136 6.708204
green  0.081172 0.000000 0.107647 4.472136
blue   4.472136 0.107647 0.000000 0.073217
red    6.708204 4.472136 0.073217 0.000000
```

I want to subset `m1` to a new matrix that only contains the rows in common with `m2`. The final result should look like:

```
> m3
            red      blue    green    
red    0.000000  4.472136 6.708204 
blue   4.472136  0.000000 2.236068 
green  6.708204  2.236068 0.000000
```

Note that in the "real" data, the matrices are hundreds of dimensions. The `subset` command seems to be for subsetting data in reference to itself, not in reference to other data frames or matrices? Anyway I tried creating an index of the matches like so:

```
index <- m1 %in% m2
```

which is fine, but I get an error when trying to transform this object into a new matrix using cbind or a for loop. I know there must be a reasonably quick or elegant way to do this, but documentation seems a bit terse on this subject. Ideally after transforming `m1` to `m3`, I want to perform some basic arithmetic operations on the values in the matching elements of `m2` and `m3` such as m2(2,3) - m3(3,2) = -2.128421. Hope this makes sense.

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: +1 for a clear question with expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  m3<-m1[row.names(m1) %in% row.names(m2),]
               red   yellow     blue    green    black
    red   0.000000 2.236068 4.472136 6.708204 8.944272
    blue  4.472136 2.236068 0.000000 2.236068 4.472136
    green 6.708204 4.472136 2.236068 0.000000 2.236068


     m3[,rownames(m3)]
           red     blue    green
red   0.000000 4.472136 6.708204
blue  4.472136 0.000000 2.236068
green 6.708204 2.236068 0.000000
```

Comment: @amurphy :You may want to check the answer as accepted if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `merge(m1,m2,all.x=FALSE,all.y=TRUE,by="colorrow")`.  First have to take the rownames of each matrix into a column named `colorrow`.